# How to change device identity in the internet

Tags: internet

When connected, the internet is able to know the kind of device I am using (i.e. to know if its a PC or a smartphone). I want to know if it is possible to trick the data (about device identity) that goes to the internet so that I can choose whether my device shows as a phone or a PC.

Comment: @TiagoCaleira - not so - MAC addresses are not shared on the internet and only contain a semi-unique ID and interface manufacturer info - nothing about the device typr - although I guess if it's a Huawei it's probably a phone. Of-course a Samsung associated Mac could be just about anything - computer, phone,tv,printer for example.

Comment: @davidgo I see. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the (implied) assumption that you are referring to web browsing, yes - its fairly easy to change this. The identification is passed by the web browser to the server with each page requested in what is called the "User Agent String". Change this and you will change what the server thinks.

This can most easily be done by getting a plugin for the browser to manipulate the string - there are any number of these available for Chrome and Firefox.

The advice to change your MAC address is falacious - MAC addresses are not available to the Internet except in exceptional circumstances where there is a badly written proprietary program - they are generally only used between the devices and the local router, and indeed there are some ways to get into the net without a MAC address (for example a cellular modem).

In practice it's virtually never done - because it's a hacking technique that will trigger all kinds of alarms and does not work for most users - who are behind NAT,  but it's theoretically possible to "fingerprint" an OS remotely and infer the type of OS - otherwise a remote computer can't tell what device you are using unless a program you are running tells it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Developer Tools" and set them to simulate a mobile device like a smart phone or a tablet. In Google Chrome go to main menu (3 dots) -> More Tools -> Developer Tools (CTRL + SHIFT + i or F12). Click on the "Toggle device toolbar" (CTRL + SHIFT + M)

[image]

Choose the mobile device you would like to use or costumize one. Click the Toggle device toolbar again to go back to PC version.

As an alternative you can download a mobile operating system like Andoid, install it in a virtual machine and access the website you want to test with that virtual machine.